# Text editor for developers

Tags: text-editor

What's the text editor that appears in the photo on the "Ubuntu for Developers" presentation on the Ubuntu website?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Give us a link to that presentation...

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/developers cornelius

Comment: http://assets.ubuntu.com/sites/ubuntu/1036/u/img/desktop/image-fordevelopers.jpg @Cornelius

Answer (score 4):

That is [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text). It is not free.

Comment: Free alternatives are jEdit and Kate, but different in the way they work and look.

Comment: Geany is my personal favourite

Comment: I don't see it explicitly on their website, is the beta version evaluation-only too? http://www.sublimetext.com/3

Comment: To be more specific, the license you have to purchase is not free, but there is a free trial until you buy the license. This trial lasts for an indefinite period of time.

Answer (score 4):

This is [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) (as already pointed out by Cornelius).

But I can not resist my urge to introduce you to [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs), the [most wonderful editor](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).

Let me tell you: Emacs can do wonders. If you learn it then you can edit text with amazing speed. You can customize it the way you want. You can write your own functions and what not! And most importantly, it is opensource (Sublime Text is not opensourced).
So if you are still deciding which editor to use, I will advice you to go for Emacs.

If you are only concerned about the look then you can do the same with Emacs. Here is a picture of my Emacs:

[image]

Comment: http://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: Ah emacs.. great OS, just misses a good editor.

Comment: Yeah..I always wonder why is ubuntu not providing emacs pre-installed...even MAC does it!

Comment: Hy, guis recently i'm using the atom editor, what do you think about it?